# Sprite Kit Select SKNode below another SKNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm creating an iOS app with Sprite Kit & I'm trying to select (onTouchBegan) a SKNode that lies below another SKNode. The structure is : FirstLayer(SKNode) - SecondLayer(SKNode) & 3rd Layer (SKNode). I'm trying to select the SecondLayer and move it around onTouchMove.
The current problem is that now touch recognises the 3rdLayer. Can you help me ?

Comment: use if (zPosition == x) {}

Comment: can u please give me more details ?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Scott's comment, the `zPosition` property of any `SKNode` is essentially the layer it lies on, with the higher layer numbers being "closer" to the front of the screen. Therefore if you want to have `nodeB` on top of `nodeA`, then `nodeA` would have a `zPosition` with a higher number than that of a, such as:

```
nodeA.zPosition = 1
nodeB.zPosition = 2
```

If you set the `zPosition` of a node when you create it, you can set a conditional check on the zPosition of a touched node in the 'touchesBegan' method. Following the above example, if you would like to touch `nodeA` and not`nodeB`, you would check that the `zPosition` of the node being touched is equal to `1`:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if(node.zPosition == 1){
        //do stuff to nodeA here
    }
}
```

I think this is what Scott was getting at, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i managed to iterate through childrens and select by the zPosition, but i cannot drag the item i need. Smh like : for(SKNode *node in self.children) and select the node with the if Condition